# How to place existing Story Issues under an Epic Issue in Jira?

Tags: jira

In Jira I have some existing Issues that are Stories.
How can I place them under an Epic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Jira GreenHopper (v6.0.6) there is a new feature. Jira > Agile > board > Plan, drag and drop the Story Issue onto the Epic.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the Epic Link field to be shown (in your projects screen scheme).  Then every card will have a field UI for selecting which Epic it is associated with.

This is the modern / current convention.

Answer (score 1):

You can also configure the Board to group the cards by Epic in Configure Board->Swimlanes->Base Swimlanes on Epics.
To really put issues "under" an Epic the Structure Plugin might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using an old view, navigate to the story page. There should be a *Epic Link* field. Clicking on it and changing the value of it, should move story to the appropriate *Epic*.